# How do people deal with asp.net membership/role/profile in real website?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I don't like asp.net profile provider store all profile info in one or two row in the database, but I want to use membership/profile API for authentication purpose.

Customize membership/role/profile provider requires big big upfront efforts, which may cause more mess later.

So how do people deal with that normally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to use asp.net profiles to store additional information if you don't want to. Instead you can store it in a separate table and link it to aspnet_Users table like shown here: [Storing additional information](http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials/storing-additional-user-information-vb)

Comment: +1 Based on the Ops criteria, Profiles are not good and should be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can use the built-in
   [SqlMembershipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlmembershipprovider.aspx), which is
   installed by running 
   `aspnet_regsql.exe`.
2. You do not have to use profiles if
   you don't like them.
3. Customizing membership/role/profile
   providers is really not that big of
   a deal.